# mvn: assign depenendecy to repository

Tags: maven

I need to add this repository in order to be able to download this dependency:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>confluent</id>
    <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka.streams.avro-serde.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, mvn is trying to download all other dependencies using this repository.

How could I set that only above dependency uses above `confluent` repository?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot relate dependencies to repositories.

But this is usually no problem because Maven will go through all repositories to find your dependencies, so it will eventually find them.

If one is very slow (and slows down the downloads), try to place it at the end.

Comment: Note: I think this would technically be possible by creating multiple modules where different repositories are used in different modules and configure it so that one module is dependent on another module with the dependencies of the said repository. However, that seems like unnecessary work.

Comment: @dan1st This is pretty clever, but like many clever solutions, it would also be pretty confusing.

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to mention it for completeness (and haven't tested it).